# Does lodash's filter function take a context?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, underscore.js, lodash

I've had a look at the [lodash filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) documentation and it's unclear whether the third parameter is a context.

I'm using a cytoscape plugin (dagre) and it seems to pass `this` as a 3 argument. When I pause the execution before the filter method is called, `this` is defined. But within the call `this` is undefined.

I had a look at the [underscore filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) documentation and it seems to take a third argument as a context. So I'm kinda guessing that the plugin originally used underscore then maybe changed to lodash. The project I'm working on is using lodash.

I can't understand why `this` is null at that point in my could. It could be project specific but I just want to be clear on the third parameter of lodash's filter.

Is the definition of lodash's filter exactly the same as underscore's filter? It does not seem so from the documentation.

Comment: What third parameter, there's no 3rd parameter on lodash `filter` method.

Comment: @chsdk Yeah... I would have thought you could replace underscore with lodash. But underscore can take a third parameter while lodash does not.

Comment: Lodash 3 `filter` has third context parameter. It's removed in Lodash 4.

Comment: @Tushar Damn... This means I have to take a look at the cytoscape plugin on github. Just checked and your are right... This sucks. Maybe you should post that as an answer?

Comment: I guess the solution is for me to use underscore.

Comment: You don't need lodash nor underscore. You can do it natively. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @Kulvar. True. I inherited the project with lodash and there are some functions I use like `_.get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the [**lodash `filter` method**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter), unlike [**underscore `filter` method**](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), doesn't provide an option for a `context` argument, as it takes only two arguments:

> **Arguments**
>
> - collection (Array|Object): The collection to iterate over.
> - [predicate=_.identity] (Function): The function invoked per    iteration.

What you can do is to use the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the callback function to the desired `context` object, like this:

```
_.filter(array, callback.bind(context));
```

**Note:**

Note that Javascript has its own **[`Array#filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** which already provides this option.

Answer (score 4):

Well you can always define your own context using `Function.prototype.bind`.

```
_.filter([…], 
  function (o) {
    console.log(this.id); //100
    //than return something based on o
    return o.active
  }.bind({id: 100})
);
```

[Doc on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: You answer is also acceptable. Up voted it. Chose the other because it talks about the fact that lodash's filter method differs from the one in underscore. But thanks for the answer. Appreciate it :-)